# Is there a way to end (terminate) a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, terminate

I am creating a downloader app in **python using tkinter and urllib.request** and I have used thread to divide it into two parts(one responsible for the main app usage and the other responsible to use the information in the main app and via **urllib.request** download the file mentioned) and I want to terminate the thread whenever the user hits a specific button(to work as a cancel button), so is there a way to do kill a thread or should I use multi-processing instead?

Comment: Does this answers your doubt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread

Comment: You should ask: *is there a way to break a `urllib.request`?*

Comment: Breaking the urllib.request was my initial thought but there were issues with the program that I had to turn it into a thread and I am happy with it but I want to end the thread with a button so that it would work as a cancel button.(Actually, if you have a way to break the urllib.request I would appreciate it if you tell me.)